# Vba Count rows in unopened excel document (from vba word)

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use vba from word to count the amount of rows that my list in excel has. The problem is that I do not seem to be able to use a `exWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` function on an excel file, which is on a usb drive, that I open via vba.

I have tried to figure out if I am opening the excel file wrong, but I was able to get a value from a single cell using `exWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1)`

My code:

```vb
    Private Sub B_FillForm_Click()

    Dim objExcel As Object
    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set exWb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("D:\DATA.xlsx")
    Dim last_row As Long
    last_row = exWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    MsgBox (last_row)

    exWb.Close

    Set exWb = Nothing


    End Sub
```

My excel file currently has A1-A5 filled in.

I expect the output to be a messagebox displaying 5, but the actual output is an error message displaying:

> "Runtime error 424, Object required"

Comment: You don't declare `exWb`?

Comment: I thought I did that with Set exWb. How would I do this correctly?

Comment: @TimDeBlaeji You first need to create (declare) a workbook object for you then to set the reference. Namely, include `Dim exWb As Workbook` in your declarations. Your code should run.

Comment: The issue is probably the unqualified `Rows.Count` imbeded in your `last lastrow =` line.  Change to `exWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count`.  Word doesn't know what `Rows` is. (Note that while it is better to declare `Dim exWb As Object` since you are using late binding, this in itself won't cause the error.  Also , using `Option Explicit` is always a good idea)

Comment: Note that the same applies to `xlUp` - Word doesn't know that either

Comment: @chrisneilsen do you mind sharing more information on the late binging method that you mention above. Would love to learn more!

Comment: @dean [have a look here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/help/245115/using-early-binding-and-late-binding-in-automation&ved=2ahUKEwilwsLQw6bjAhWC7nMBHZCYAcsQFjAFegQIBBAB&usg=AOvVaw0AHHfs-bNfyPVstwMhaYeq&cshid=1562630468928)

Comment: @chrisneilsen With having fixed the `Dim exWb As Object` and `exWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count` I still get a compile error displaying that my user defined type is not defined. So do I still need to change the `Rows` part?

Answer (score -1):

You need to declare your workbook object before you can set the reference.

```vb
 Private Sub B_FillForm_Click()

    Dim objExcel As Object
    Dim exWb As Workbook  'missing from your code
    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set exWb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("D:\DATA.xlsx")
    Dim last_row As Long
    last_row = exWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    MsgBox (last_row)

    exWb.Close

    Set exWb = Nothing

End Sub
```